# "Remove formatting" from API

Tags: google-sheets, formatting, transformation, google-sheets-api

I am using a custom API in Google Sheets where I get data in a cell for e.g. 4290590000.0, however I cannot change the format of the cells to number (General by default). With this it is not possible to use conditional formatting on these cells.

Is there someway to work or program around this program, or is this with the API builder to fix it?

Comment: Thanks, simple and solves the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set a custom number format. Check out this [guide for setting a custom format](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/samples/formatting#set_a_custom_datetime_or_decimal_format_for_a_range) and [this reference](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/formats) for how to write your format pattern.